# Public variable loses value on button click event asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have checkboxes in my asp.net gridview and I have a method to select multiple checkboxes and that works great. After that when the user inputs a value in the textbox to be updated to the rows selected the values I just set are null again? I have included my method of checking multiple items and my update button. Why are the values not being retained and how can I fix it?

public variables

```
public string values = "";
public string salesorderNumber;
```

Multiple checkboxes

```
protected void SelectCheckBox_OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chk = sender as CheckBox;

    var rows = dropdeadGridView.Rows;
    int count = dropdeadGridView.Rows.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        bool isChecked = ((CheckBox)rows[i].FindControl("SelectCheckBox")).Checked;
        if (isChecked)
        {
            values += rows[i].Cells[1].Text + ",";
            rows[i].BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            rows[i].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            rows[i].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Inset;
        }
    }
}
```

Update Button

```
protected void UpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    App_Code.GridData gridData = new App_Code.GridData();

        if (loadnumTextBox.Text == "" && RadDateTimePicker1.SelectedDate != null)
        {
            SqlConnection dbConn = App_Code.DBHelper.getConnection();
            try
            {
                using (dbConn)
                {
                    SqlCommand addJob = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE ORDER_DETAIL SET DropDeadTime = @DropDeadTime WHERE SALES_ORDER_NUMBER = @SalesOrderNumber", dbConn);
                    //addJob.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SalesOrderNumber", Convert.ToInt32(IDTextBox.Text));
                    addJob.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SalesOrderNumber", values);
                    addJob.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DropDeadTime", RadDateTimePicker1.SelectedDate);
                    dbConn.Open();
                    addJob.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                NotificationLabel.Text = "Updated!";
                NotificationLabel.Visible = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            BindList();
        }

        if (loadnumTextBox.Text != "" && RadDateTimePicker1.SelectedDate == null)
        {
            SqlConnection dbConn = App_Code.DBHelper.getConnection();
            try
            {
                using (dbConn)
                {
                    SqlCommand addJob = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE ORDER_DETAIL SET LOAD_NUMBER = @LOAD_NUMBER WHERE SALES_ORDER_NUMBER = @SalesOrderNumber", dbConn);
                    addJob.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SalesOrderNumber", salesorderNumber);
                    addJob.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LOAD_NUMBER", loadnumTextBox.Text);
                    dbConn.Open();
                    addJob.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                NotificationLabel.Text = "Updated!";
                NotificationLabel.Visible = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            BindList();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to live between requests you'll have to use something like session-state, view-state, a cookie, or a HTML form / request value.

ASP.NET is stateless meaning it does not keep it state from post back to postback.

You need a static one if you want to achieve your goal.

Comment: Do you have an example I can look at?

Comment: There are tons of examples, before that read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Would you recommend one over another?